# I need a groovy criteria to get all the elements after i make sort on nullable inner object

Tags: grails

I have two domain classes named IpPatient,Ward as shown below.

```
class IpPatient {
  String ipRegNo
  Ward ward

  static constraints = {
    ward nullable:true
    ipRegNo nullable:false
  }
}

class Ward
{
  String name;

  static constraints = {
    name nullable:true
  }
}
```

now i would like to create criteria like

```
def criteria=IpPatient.createCriteria()
return criteria.list(max:max , offset:offset) {
  order("ward.name","asc")  
  createAlias('ward', 'ward', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
}
```

At present `IpPatient` table has 13 records, where 8 records of `IpPatient` doesn't have ward because ward can be null.

when i sort with `wardName` i am getting 5 records those contain ward.

I need a criteria to get all the elements after i make sort on nullable inner object.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be looking for an HQL-based approach, but this should do the trick:

```
IpPatient.findAll("from IpPatient as i left outer join i.ward as w order by w.name asc")
```

Comment: I need Criteria @Andrew, not Hql-based approach.